# What does "to give up someone " mean?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean that you no longer want someone, or that you have to leave someone, like it or not?

Comment: Give a sentence in context. There might be multiple meanings or it might be vague.

Comment: Without further context this is just Too Broad. But in any *given* context, it should be easy enough to match the usage to the relevant dictionary definition.

Comment: What about in a phrase like "Never going to give you up"? eg in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could mean that you are turning them in, to the police for example. It could also mean you are giving them up, like a bad habit.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you downvote, please post a comment with your rationale.

Comment: +1 Also ending a relationship, even if reluctantly.

Comment: Good thought - I hadn't considered that one

Comment: @bib: Though for relationships, one would say give up **on**, as in putting distance between yourself and the other.

Comment: @Damon *I want my wife back, despite her affair with you! Will you give her up?*

Comment: @bib: Ah, that is a good counter-example :-) 100% opposite meaning (regarding intent).

Answer (score 5):

To give someone up might apply to someone putting up their child for adoption, or something of a similar nature.

> She gave the baby up because she wasn't ready to be a mother.
>
> She wants to give the baby up because she's not ready to be a mother.

Answer (score 0):

The term "to give someone up" is often used when a person lets someone move on with their life.

An example would be a love triangle where Person A loves Person B but Person B loves Person C instead.

In this case if Person A was to back off, give some space to B and C you could say that person say has given them up.

Answer (score 0):

If "give up someone" is used in a "dating" situation, it means to let them go, or to stop dating them, etc.

In a different context, it means to "turn in" (e.g. a suspected criminal) to the authorities.